# Помогите с отступами

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста разместить форму и текст нормально, не криво.[image: Меню]

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu_text">
        <a href="#">Главная</a>
        <a href="#">Статьи</a>
        <a href="#">Файлы</a>
    </div>
    <form class="search" action="" method="">
        <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="search-txt" />
        <input class="search-btn" type="image" src="img/search-b.jpg" />
    </form>
```

CSS:

```
 .menu {
     background: url(img / bm.jpg) center no - repeat;
     padding: 20 px;
 }
 .menu_text {
     position: absolute;
     margin - left: 10 px;

 }
 .menu_text a {
     font - family: "Times New Roman"
     serif;
     color: #fff;
     text - decoration: none;
     font - size: 25 px;
     margin - right: 60 px;

 }
 .search {
     margin - left: 650 px;

 }
```

Comment: Код предоставьте. fiddle сделайте... А-то я в Фотошопе сейчас картинку подправлю и пришлю Вам как ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы используете в качестве кнопки картинку, которая по размеру больше текстового поля.

Например,

```
<div>
    <form><input type="text"><input type="button" value="Поиск"></form>
</div>
```

...выводит всё в одну строку. Зачем вам "химичить" с картинками вместо кнопок, когда можно сделать проще? Тем более стили для кнопок можно задать через CSS:

```
button { /* стили для тега <button> */ }
input[type=button] { /* стили для тега <input type="button"> */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Соглашаюсь с DeFF, а еще причиной может быть то что в этих элементов display: inline-block; Тут следует добавить свойство vertical-align: middle и должно отображаться на одном уровне. Но лучше делать нормальными кнопками.